# How to reduce the array dimensions in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data array,

`dat <- array(NA, c(115,45,10))`

How can I get a new data array

`dat1<- array(NA, c(115,45))` by averaging `dat` by the third dimension?

Thanks

Comment: What you've posted needs a ")" and a lower case "c". Also, it produces an array of 51750 NA values. Not exactly sure what you're asking here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
dat1 <- apply( dat, c(1,2), mean )
```

the c(1,2) means keep the 1st and 2nd dimensions and apply the function (mean) over the rest (3rd).